# Event Created In User Control Not Working

Tags: c#, vb.net, events, user-controls

When you put the tool inside UserControl not be activated from inside the event window

Code In UserControl :

```vb
 Public Class Commands

    Event Clicks(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)

    Private Sub Button1_ClickEvent(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.ClickEvent
          msgbox "Is Work In UserControl"
          RaiseEvent Clicks(sender, e)

    End Sub
```

Code In Form :

```vb
Private Sub Commands1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Commands1.Clicks
    MsgBox("No Work IN Form")

End Sub
```

Comment: If the above code is correct, then you need to change `Handles Button1.ClickEvent` to `Handles Button1.Click`.

Comment: The CodeJock Control Name Event Click Is ClickEvent

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the event as public

```vb
Public Event Clicks(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
```

This makes the event visible from outside of the user control so you can react to it from the form.

Comment: You are not offering any information to work with. You have to describe in detail what is not working. What error messages do you get? What is the behaviour you want and what behaviour do you get instead? This isn't twitter, use the space.